# how to handle comma string in fputcsv in php?

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

how to put array values in csv in correct format?
here is my code:

```
$title = Business - Research, MPhil/PhD | University of Greenwich | Research degrees;    
$description = '';
$keywords = '';
$list = $title.",".$keywords.",".$description;
$fp = fopen('public/scrap-meta-title-info.csv', 'a+');
        foreach ($list as $line) {
            fputcsv($fp, split(',', $line));
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

here is my array result:
     Business - Research, MPhil/PhD | University of Greenwich | Research degrees,,
but when i put these values in csv then my title string break and put half value in keyword how i put title value complete in title field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delimiter is , and inside of your title you have a comma. Choose another delimiter, such as ** to concatenate and split on:

Such as:

```
$list = $title."**".$keywords."**".$description;

fputcsv($fp, split('\*\*', $line));
```

Comment: Warning: split(): REG_BADRPT in /mnt/

Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean

Comment: @MuhammadArif Right, my mistake. `split()` requires escaping of special characters defined by regexp. Therefore, we need to add `\ ` before. Please look again.